# R output BOTH maximum and minimum value by group in dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe

Let's say I have a dataframe of `Name` and `value`, is there any ways to extract **BOTH** minimum and maximum values within `Name` in a single function?

```
set.seed(1)
df <- tibble(Name = rep(LETTERS[1:3], each = 3), Value = sample(1:100, 9))

# A tibble: 9 x 2
  Name  Value
  <chr> <int>
1 A        27
2 A        37
3 A        57
4 B        89
5 B        20
6 B        86
7 C        97
8 C        62
9 C        58
```

The output should contains **TWO** columns only (`Name` and `Value`).
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `range` to get `max` and `min` value and use it in `summarise` to get different rows for each `Name`.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(Name) %>%
  summarise(Value = range(Value), .groups = "drop")

#  Name  Value
#  <chr> <int>
#1 A        27
#2 A        57
#3 B        20
#4 B        89
#5 C        58
#6 C        97
```

If you have large dataset using `data.table` might be faster.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, .(Value = range(Value)), Name]
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use `dplyr::group_by()` and `dplyr::summarise()` like this:

```r
library(dplyr)

set.seed(1)
df <- tibble(Name = rep(LETTERS[1:3], each = 3), Value = sample(1:100, 9))

df %>% 
    group_by(Name) %>% 
    summarise(
        maximum = max(Value),
        minimum = min(Value)
    )
```

This outputs:

```r
# A tibble: 3 × 3
  Name  maximum minimum
  <chr>   <int>   <int>
1 A          68       1
2 B          87      34
3 C          82      14
```

What's a little odd is that my original `df` object looks a little different than yours, in spite of the seed:

```r
# A tibble: 9 × 2
  Name  Value
  <chr> <int>
1 A        68
2 A        39
3 A         1
4 B        34
5 B        87
6 B        43
7 C        14
8 C        82
9 C        59
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! But then the result would have three columns instead of two, which will require an extra pivot operation. And yeah I'm not sure why my `set.seed` is always different from others

Answer (score 2):

I'm currently using `rbind()` together with `slice_min()` and `slice_max()`, but I think it may not be the best way or the most efficient way when the dataframe contains millions of rows.

```
library(tidyverse)

rbind(df %>% group_by(Name) %>% slice_max(Value), 
      df %>% group_by(Name) %>% slice_min(Value)) %>%
  arrange(Name)

# A tibble: 6 x 2
# Groups:   Name [3]
  Name  Value
  <chr> <int>
1 A        57
2 A        27
3 B        89
4 B        20
5 C        97
6 C        58
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `aggregate`.

```
aggregate(Value ~ Name, df, range)
#   Name Value.1 Value.2
# 1    A       1      68
# 2    B      34      87
# 3    C      14      82
```

Answer (score 1):

In `base R`, the output format can be created with `tapply/stack` - do a group by `tapply` to get the output as a named `list` or `range`, `stack` it to two column `data.frame` and change the column names if needed

```
setNames(stack(with(df, tapply(Value, Name, FUN = range)))[2:1], names(df))
  Name Value
1    A    27
2    A    57
3    B    20
4    B    89
5    C    58
6    C    97
```